# equalize order of two arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, optimization

**Situation:**

Two arrays with integer values (length of both is same).

**What I need:**

Array1 should have the same order as arrays2. That means, the maximal value of array1 should be at the positon of maximal value of array2, and so on.

**Examples:**

```
1) 
Array1= [2, 3, 5, 7]
Array2= [4, 9, 6, 1]
Target= [3, 7, 5, 2]
```

Explanation: 4 is the second lowest value of array2, so on this positon in the target array should be the second lowest value of array1 which is 3.  ...

```
2) 
Array1= [9, 1, 4, 8]
Array2= [1, 2, 3, 4]
Target= [1, 4, 8, 9]
```

Explanation: array2 is sorted from lowest to highest, so  array1 just have to be sorted the same way.

**Question:**

What is the best way to do this in short time for arrays of length [10] - [999]. Of course I could write a loop to go through all numbers of an array and check for each, which position it has (loop inside loop), do that for both arrays and then build a new one with the right order. That would take a long time and needs a lot of resources (most CPU and some MEM). 
I am looking for the most efficient way doing it. (optimazation for time not mem, it is more important to do it quick then to save mem).

I hope its clear, what i want.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in O(n log(n)) time complexity.
Sort a list of indices by the values of Array2 and apply the reverse order to Array1:

```
public class EqualizeOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] array1 = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
        final int[] array2 = new int[] { 4, 9, 6, 1 };
        final Integer[] indices = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

        //sort the indices accordingly to array2
        Arrays.sort(indices, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return Integer.compare(array2[o1], array2[o2]);
            }
        });


        //array1 must be sorted before applying reverse order
        Arrays.sort(array1);

        int[] target = new int[array1.length];
        //applying the reverse order to output array
        for (int i = 0; i<target.length; i++) {
            target[indices[i]] = array1[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Array1 = "+Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.println("Array2 = "+Arrays.toString(array2));
        System.out.println("indices= "+Arrays.toString(indices));
        System.out.println("Target = "+Arrays.toString(target));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array1 = [2, 3, 5, 7]
Array2 = [4, 9, 6, 1]
indices= [3, 0, 2, 1]
Target = [3, 7, 5, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, this way is a bit faster then my own. I don´t think, it will be possible to do it much faster but if anyone have a better idea, it would be nice.

Comment: The theoretical lower bound complexity for comparison sorting is considered Omega(n log n) so it would be a huge advantage for computer science if someone finds a faster general solution to the problem of equalizing the order of an array, because that would solve the sorting problem also faster. However there may be faster custom solutions using Hashing for example. But I don't know anything about the data you are handling, so I can't say anything about that :)